# Round and round the Yamanote Line

Tags: knowledge, story

I just received a call from my friend who only speaks German. Last I heard, he was in a trip in Japan.

Here is a translation of how the call went:

> **Him:** I went around the loop line. It was colored green, and I saw big buildings.
>
> **Me:** What? Tokyo?
>
> **Him:** Yes. But I don't know where I am!
>
> **Me:** [clearly worried] So what did you see? It has windows!
>
> **Him:** A man was blocking it. The only thing I could see was a bunch of tracks and a railway construction site. And something about the Olympics. [pauses] And I got off 12 stops later!
>
> **Me:** Saw anything else?
>
> **Him:** Oh, and a thing that said "K-something." That was the first station after.
>
> **Me:** Oh, so you are at _______.
>
> **Him:** Oh.... yeah, that's right...

So where was he at?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, a response to the answerer to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

The Olympics-related construction site must be for

> the new Takanawa Gateway Station, between Shinagawa and Tamachi stations.

I'd hoped that

> whichever way around you go from there, 12 stops would take you to the same station. Unfortunately, 12 stops clockwise starting at Shinagawa takes you to Mejiro, and 12 stops anticlockwise starting at Tamachi takes you to Nishi-Nippori.

However, OP has now added that at the next station there was *a thing that said "K-something"*. I can't escape the suspicion that there are probably things matching that description either way, but

> I guess what they have in mind is the signs for the Keikyu line which say "KK" on them. That would be Shinagawa rather than Tamachi, in which case the friend is probably now at **Mejiro** station.

Comment: Yes I screwed up a tad bit. I forgot that he could've been going around 2 ways, not just one.

Comment: If you make it 15 stops, then it works unless I miscounted...

Comment: I don't understand where the "only speaks German" comes in to it.

Comment: @MichaelMaggs: Oh yeah! The "only speaks German" is because on the Yamanote line, there is English text, therefore I had to get rid of that. (Or else it'd been too easy.) And you're right for the 15 stops, however that wasn't how it worked when I thought about it.

Comment: If you want to fix it then I can adjust my answer accordingly, and then we have a slightly cleverer puzzle and a correct answer :-).

Comment: Not sure it's right to say there is 'English text'.  Station names such as 'Tamachi' aren't English but are Romaji transliterations into the Latin alphabet of the Japanese.

Comment: Ah, I see you fixed it a different way. Let's see whether I correctly guessed your intent :-).

Comment: @TzuLi Did I get the intended answer, or is there some point I'm still missing?